# Spring-boot app connect with Apache Artemis cluster

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

Spring-Boot can  auto-configure a Connection Factory when it get that Artemis is available on the classpath. But how we can configure spring-boot application to native Artemis cluster (multiple nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TRICT value of message-load-balancing in broker.xml. then you need to create as many connections as many nodes you are using. In spring you can use MessageListenerContainer to listen to the consumer.
[Here](https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/ApacheArtemisCluster) is a sample app to connect to the cluster(with 2 node)